# Overflow error but value is actually zero

Tags: numerics

I got the following error in my computation:

"Infinite expression $\frac{1}{0.*10^{3576} + 0.*10^{3576} i}$ encountered. "

It looks to me that the denominator is 0 but it is not being recognised as such. I checked for similar questions in this stackexchange but I'm not sure if this has been asked before. Is there anyway to circumvent this problem?

Context: I am trying to calculate the spectrum of resonance fluorescence of a 4 level system. 
This error doesn't always occur, occasionally the equation hits overflow and the NIntegrate returns an error and a solution.

Here are the code which gave this error:

```
    (*16x16 Louvillian of the system*)
    lou={{-1000., 0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 
          0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 1000., 0, 0, 0, 0, 500000., 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I,
           0, 0, 1.*10^9}, {0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, -1000. + 0. I, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0}, {0, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, -5.00251*10^8 + 3.23135*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 
          0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 
          0}, {0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, -1.00025*10^9 + 3.23135*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0,
           0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0. - 1.5*10^9 I}, {0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0, 0, -1000. + 0. I, 
          0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0}, {1000., 0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0, 
          0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, -1000., 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I,
           1.*10^9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500000.}, {0, 0, 0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, -1.00025*10^9 + 3.23135*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 
          0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0. + 4.45358*10^7 I, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, -5.00251*10^8 + 3.23135*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 
          0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 
          0, -5.00251*10^8 - 3.23135*10^9 I, 0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0,
           0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, -1.00025*10^9 - 3.23135*10^9 I, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I,
           0, 0, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, -1.0005*10^9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 
          0, -1.0005*10^9 + 0. I, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.00025*10^9 - 3.23135*10^9 I, 
          0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, 0, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I}, {0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0. - 4.45358*10^7 I, -5.00251*10^8 - 3.23135*10^9 I, 
          0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0}, {0, 0, 0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, -1.0005*10^9 + 0. I, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
          0. - 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 1.5*10^9 I, 0, 
          0, -1.0005*10^9}}

    louiwsl = (lou - I Δω t)*IdentityMatrix[16]

(*equilibrium population & coherences of the 4 level system*)
reqm={{0.38997 - 1.84338*10^-16 I, 
  0.0105572 - 1.10701*10^-16 I, -0.00326682 + 
   1.26775*10^-8 I, -0.118545 + 0.036695 I}, {0.0105572 + 
   3.04385*10^-17 I, 
  0.38997 - 3.06618*10^-16 I, -0.118545 + 0.036695 I, -0.00326682 + 
   1.26775*10^-8 I}, {-0.00326682 - 1.26775*10^-8 I, -0.118545 - 
   0.036695 I, 
  0.11003 - 1.11906*10^-16 I, -8.86105*10^-9 - 
   1.13631*10^-16 I}, {-0.118545 - 0.036695 I, -0.00326682 - 
   1.26775*10^-8 I, -8.86105*10^-9 + 2.87021*10^-17 I, 
  0.11003 - 7.83993*10^-17 I}}

inlou1 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 1]];
inlou5 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 5]];
inlou9 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 9]];
inlou13 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 13]];
inlou2 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 2]];
inlou6 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 6]];
inlou10 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 10]];
inlou14 = LinearSolve[louiwsl, UnitVector[16, 14]];

(*Calculating intensity spectrum*)
is14 = 2*Re[-inlou1[[13]]*reqm[[1, 4]] - inlou5[[13]]*reqm[[2, 4]] - 
     inlou9[[13]]*reqm[[3, 4]] - inlou13[[13]]*reqm[[4, 4]]];
iss14 = is14 /. Δω -> 2 \[Pi]v;
is23 = 2*Re[-inlou2[[10]]*reqm[[1, 3]] - inlou6[[10]]*reqm[[2, 3]] - 
     inlou10[[10]]*reqm[[3, 3]] - inlou14[[10]]*reqm[[4, 3]]];
iss23 = is23 /. Δω -> 2 \[Pi]v];

f0=-20*^9;f1=20*^9;
NIntegrate[iss14, {v, f0, f1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
 AccuracyGoal -> 8, Exclusions -> {0, Automatic}]
NIntegrate[iss23, {v, f0, f1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
 AccuracyGoal -> 8, Exclusions -> {0, Automatic}]
```

Comment: Since you have such large numbers (e.g. 10^9) in your expressions, isn't there some way you can re-scale your variables and parameters so that these numbers are more reasonable, more on the order of 1? This is important from both a physics standpoint and a numerics standpoint, and it's a good skill to learn. That type of rescaling will help with a lot of underflow and overflow issues when doing numerics.

Comment: Alright, I can certainly do that. It hasn't occurred to me before. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. `1/0.` is an infinite expression, as the message states.

Comment: @JohnDoty oh yeah, you are right, I must have gotten confused. However, I have actually encountered the error where it is simply the overflow of say, 0.∗103576. Shall I remove the question or edit it?

Comment: You get things like ` 0.∗103576` when you subtract large approximate numbers that aren't machine numbers and the difference is effectively zero. Consider that `10^10000. - 10^10000` yields `0.*10^9988`. The `10^9988` encodes the uncertainty of the result.

Comment: OK, got it. I will make some improvements to the code and see if this error still pops up. Thanks!